# Error message shows up when I start working on a previously saved notebook on Mathematica

Tags: warning-messages

I am new to Mathematica and hope this is not something very obvious.

Whenever I start a new session on Mathematica and try to work on a previously saved file, Mathematica shows me the error message I have attached here. Regardless of what I choose here, the file wouldn't work properly. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Obtain some understanding of this message by reading `InitializationCell` in the documentation.  However, because your notebook does not work properly no matter which button you select, there may be a problem in it that has nothing to do with Initialization Cells.  I recommend that  you provide more details, like what are the symptoms of the notebook not working properly.

Comment: Maybe nitpicking, but that isn't an *error* message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message about initialization cells isn't an error. Initialization cells are specially formatted cells that you can choose to evaluate all at once before anything else when you get this message.

As for the notebook not working, it is a little hard to advise without knowing what's in the notebook. Still, make sure you evaluate the cells in the right order. If you want to evaluate individual cells, select the cell by clicking on their brackets on the right and press (Shift+Enter). Depending on what's in the notebook, you might want to evaluate all the cells in the notebook at once by going to the Evaluation menu at the top and clicking "Evaluate Notebook."

Comment: Thank you for the informative response! This is really helpful! Everything seems to be working well now!

Answer (score 3):

First, select all the input cells on the right side, like this:

[image]

Then, apply Ctrl+8 and save changes.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is helpful!!

Comment: You're welcome and greetings, Susan! :)

Comment: You could add an explanation on what this actually does, i.e. toggling initilaization cells (which are evaluated once you run anything in the notebook)